# Which part of the code in dask.distributed is handling the sending of task to the workers?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I was going through the code of dask-distributed modules, but couldn't find out the part of the code responsible for sending the tasks to a certain worker. I could find where the tasks are getting queued on the scheduler for getting dispatched to some worker, and where the scheduler is handling events such as task_finished etc. from the workers.
But I am unable to find the part of the code which sends the tasks to the workers.

Any help or pointers will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I figured it out. It is the "send_all" method in scheduler.py of the dask.distributed module which takes care of sending the tasks to the worker. The tasks messages are sent asynchronously to the workers/clients in a batch.